Grainy Uploads to Ingragram from Illustrator
I'm having a problem with how certain images of mine are handled by Instagram.  Wondering if invoking your brain trust can solve it.
So, here's the image I'm trying to post on my Instagram story: 
The problem is no matter how I export it out of Illustrator (png or jpeg, ebedding or not embedding color profile, quality and compression method for jpeg, etc...) when I upload it to Instagram I get all these artifacts: 
This is a zoomed in detail of the same picture as above once uploaded to an Instagram story.
I even tried to change slightly the green to make sure I had a Web-safe green.
I have Upload at highest quality enabled on the Instragram settings.
I uploaded both from my phone and my mac through developer mode on the browser (Firefox).
I also tried exporting the file as a .psd and creating the necessary PNG and JPEG in Photoshop. Nothing has worked so far.
I know Instagram uses a compression algorithm, but it seems absurd there is no way to have a 426 KB picture uploaded without this green getting completely messed up.
By comparison zooming in on the green of the PNG exported image on my mac without going through Instagram looks like this:

Thought I'd try to ask for help here before I give up.
Thanks already in advance.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. These are simply jpeg compression artefacts, caused by excessive compression. This is a common problem with Instagram, and has nothing to do with Illustrator or Photoshop. It's unlikely there is anything you can do about it, except maybe use a different image sharing site.
